# Laravel: DB request saves false data

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-artisan

First i do the DB request.

```
$user=DB::table('pupil')->select('accountName')->where('accountName', '6001')->get();
```

But it returns this data.

```
[{"accountName":"6001"}]
```

And i need this data.

```
6001
```

I want only to echo 6001 and not [{"accountName":"6001"}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get only one value then used `first` method here..

```
$user = DB::table('pupil')->select('accountName')->where('accountName', '6001')->first()->accountName;
```

or used [`value`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results) method here..

> you may extract a single value from a record using the  value method.

```
DB::table('pupil')->where('accountName', '6001')->value('accountName')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
$value='{"accountName":"6001"}';
$return=json_decode($value);

print_r($return->{'accountName'});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `value` method by laravel

```
$user=DB::table('pupil')->where('accountName','=', '6001')->value('accountName');
return $user;
```

**Output:**

```
6001
```